# IDL in ATL/COM: Can I publish a const of a complex type?

Tags: com, constants, atl, idl

I know how to publish a const of a simple type in IDL, for example:

```
const long blah = 37
```

But I want to publish consts of complex types, with methods, or at least readable struct-like member fields.  For example, perhaps a type called CarType, which has accessor fields like "get_Make", "get_Model", "get_Year", "get_BasePrice", et cetera.

Then I would like to publish const instances, such as FORD_PINTO_1973.

(Please don't read too much into the example, to tell me that this particular example would lend itself better to just regular classes without const instances or something like that).

I have no idea how I would define, in IDL, the fact that FORD_PINTO_1973 has a Year field of 1973.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

IDL is for defining interfaces - contracts of what can be done on an object. Real objects implementation is out of IDL.

In order to provide a read-only property provide a getter (use `propget` attribute)  and don't provide the setter (`propput`).

Comment: IDL is not merely for defining interfaces; for example, you can define enumerations, you can define constants, you can define structs.  Given that you can define constants and that you can define structs, I don't see why it's out of the question that you might be able to define constant instances of structs, and this ability would satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Yeap, you can define structs and interfaces - those are contracts specifying how instances behave, but you can't define instances themselves.

Comment: Yes, you can define instances.  For example, you can define an instance of a long.